# import csv to mysql through java error with row compeletion

Tags: java, mysql, csv

Problem : When using SQL command - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in java program to import the csv format file into MySql DB.  But the the first row of csv is inserted into mysql table corrctly but for next row it starts with the last column of first row..

java code:

```
    try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training", "root", "");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/dummy/sample.csv' INTO TABLE csv_sample FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (trans_date,product,price,pay_type,name,city,state,country,acc_created,last_login,lat,lon)";          
                 System.out.println(loadQuery);
                  stmt.executeQuery(loadQuery);


                con.close();
}
```

csv file :

```
Transaction_date,Product,Price,Payment_Type,Name,City,State,Country,Account_Created,Last_Login,Latitude,Longitude
1/2/09 6:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,carolina,Basildon,England,United Kingdom,1/2/09 6:00,1/2/09 6:08,51.5,-1.1166667
1/2/09 4:53,Product1,1200,Visa,Betina,Parkville                   ,MO,United States,1/2/09 4:42,1/2/09 7:49,39.195,-94.68194
1/2/09 13:08,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Federica e Andrea,Astoria                     ,OR,United States,1/1/09 16:21,1/3/09 12:32,46.18806,-123.83
1/3/09 14:44,Product1,1200,Visa,Gouya,Echuca,Victoria,Australia,9/25/05 21:13,1/3/09 14:22,-36.1333333,144.75
1/4/09 12:56,Product2,3600,Visa,Gerd W ,Cahaba Heights              ,AL,United States,11/15/08 15:47,1/4/09 12:45,33.52056,-86.8025
1/4/09 13:19,Product1,1200,Visa,LAURENCE,Mickleton                   ,NJ,United States,9/24/08 15:19,1/4/09 13:04,39.79,-75.23806
1/4/09 20:11,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Fleur,Peoria                      ,IL,United States,1/3/09 9:38,1/4/09 19:45,40.69361,-89.58889
```

As you can see that every row of csv file is not having any comma(,). and it must be newline character.

My code is working just for first row in sql db.  help me!

Comment: did you try using command line(mysql cli) directly to import csv file, if yes was it successful?

Comment: Does your file have the right line separator ? Try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'` (Windows line separator) .

Comment: i have tried this. yet the same problem @Berger

Comment: not tried through the command line... actually using xammp phpmyadmin @piyushjaiswal

Comment: You forgot `IGNORE 1 ROWS`, thats messing up the whole thing, as your csv also contains `header`

Comment: i had tried that too @piyushjaiswal